# What exactly is Input size

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph, complexity-theory

When I am about to know some algorithms I confused about what exactly is input size.

For example in travelling sales person problem dynamic programming implementation takes O(2<sup>n</sup> × n<sup>2</sup>)

And Kruskal's algorithm takes
O(E log V). Though both are graph problems why TSP input size is the number of vertices n and in Kruskal's algorithm the input size is in Edges and Vertices.

How to know exactly what can be taken as input size?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is input size exactly.Please elaborate clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can state an algorithm's complexity in terms of whatever variables you like.

You should generally choose them to clearly communicate useful information about the running time of the algorithm.

Comment: So there will be no problem in choosing Edges as input size in TSP if we can measure complexity with those.Am l right??

Comment: that's correct.